# Binding jQuery event on a child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has the following javascript:

```
var w = window.open("somePage.html", '', 'width=500, height=500');
$(w).bind('someEvent', function() { alert('I see the event!'); });
```

and on **somePage.html** I attempt to trigger the event:

```
$(window).trigger('someEvent', '');
```

The event doesn't fire (it does however if I do the event binding and trigger on the same page).  I have tried all sorts of variations of binding such as using *this* and *this.window*

Am I somehow not referencing the right object from the binding side?

(I am testing this in Chrome and Firefox)

**edit:**

[David Rodrigues](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755393/david-rodrigues) was kind enough to create a jsfiddle of this question:
http://jsfiddle.net/KARgF/ & http://fiddle.jshell.net/vTQ9U/

Comment: Can you set-up a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: a jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KARgF/). ;)

Comment: Wow didn't realize you could reference another jsfiddle, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `$` still refers to the jquery in the host window. If you do this:

```
var w = window.open("somePage.html", '', 'width=500, height=500');
var $ = w.$;
$(w).bind('someEvent', function() { alert('I see the event!'); });
```

you should be good to go.