# Close child popup fire jQuery code on parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, popup, parent-child

I am doing some twitter authentication in classic asp (I know, but I can't change it). What I am doing is opening an authentication page in a popup via jQuery/JS with window.open that handels all of the rest/oauth authentication and then returns to the same page with the oauth keys I need. I would then like to close the popup and fire off some jQuery hide/show events without refreshing the page.

Code to fireoff the popup and authentication script:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#twitter-button").live("click", function() {
        jQuery("#twitter-button").attr("value", "Processing");
        jQuery("#twitter-button").removeClass();
        jQuery("#twitter-button").addClass("twitter-button-processing");
        window.open('authentication.asp','_blank','width=600,height=400');
        return false;
        });
    });
```

I then have the following code on the same page nested in some ASP for when we are redirected back:

```
if Session("OAUTH_TOKEN") <> "" And Session("OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET") <> "" Then
%>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  window.close();
  // I'd like to show/hide new buttons on the parent page here
});

</script>
<%
End If
```

The goal is to change the button with a class of twitter-button-processing displaying none but I can not get it to change in the parent window. I have tried placing            jQuery('.twitter-button-processing').hide(); in a jQuery(window).unload() function after the close but this did not produce the correct result.

I tried the solutions from [Binding jQuery event on a child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548429/binding-jquery-event-on-a-child-window) and [How to run function of parent window when child window closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112340/how-to-run-function-of-parent-window-when-child-window-closes) to no avail. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: would be a lot cleaner not using another window and simply use a dialog for your form which you submit with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up pinpointing the answer on my own. Instead of redirecting back to the same page which was getting messy, I am redirecting to a blank page from the twitter popup window with some classic ASP that checks a few session variables.

Main File

```
var someFunction = function(data){
  //some functionality
}
```

Twitter Popup Redirect window in the asp checks

```
window.opener.someFunction();
window.close();
```

This did exactly what I needed to do by calling the JS on the parent window while closing the child. Maybe this will help someone else.