# Jquery Bind click event to elements in child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that will create a child window and inside this window I want to be able to fire an alert whenever a user clicks on one of the defined html elements. The code will work as I want it to on the main window, but when I apply it to the child window it doesn't work.

When the method below runs it will output "Window loaded" to the console window, but it doesn't ever launch the click event.

```
function OpenUrl()
{
    var url = $("#urltoopen").val();
    var childwindow = window.open(url, '', 'width=800, height=500');
    childwindow.focus();
    $(document, childwindow.document).ready(function(){
        console.log("Window loaded");
        $( "div, span, li, ul, ol, input, button", childwindow).click(function(e) {
            console.log("Child click event");
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert("element clicked");
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556714/5947043, I think that might help

Comment: @ADyson tried this already it returns an error "$ is not a function". Tried messing with it a bit and cant get it to run without throwing an error

Comment: does the child page have jQuery included in it?

Comment: @ADyson no it does not. I need to use jquery on the parent page to do the binding as i need the obtain some data from the child page and store it using the parent

Comment: That'll be why it errors then - the code in that link tries to switch to using the jQuery instance in the child window. Therefore the child window needs jQuery included in it as well via a `<script` tag. You should still then be able to use that instance to retrieve data and get it back into your parent page.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery `contents` function to find child window elements

this is a working sample try it on localserver

**main.html**

```
   <html>
      <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
  <body>

      <button onclick=OpenUrl()>OPEN</button>

<script>

    function OpenUrl(){

var childwindow = window.open('test.html', '', 'width=800, height=500');
$(childwindow.document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        $(childwindow.document).contents().find( "button").click(function(e) {
            console.log("Child click event");
        });
    },500);
}); 
}



 </script>
```

**test.html**

```
<html>

<body>

<button>test</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this seems a little more promising. I tried dumping the result from calling contents(). it seems that the inner html of the page is pretty much blank "<html><head></head><body></body></html>". Am i detecting the document ready event incorrectly?

Comment: may be you have to use timeout function for a delay before adding event

Comment: @DanHastings I added a working sample into my answer

Comment: it seems it might be a google chrome thing. it works with firefox

Comment: I was getting a cross origin exception. Google chrome doesnt seem to allow it from 2 files on the same local hard disk.

Comment: @DanHastings you have to run this in localhost (or server)

Answer (score 0):

Check if  `$( "div, span, li, ul, ol, input, button", childwindow)` contains any selection?

If there are any selections, check selected elements have correct size on new window.

Comment: it has a length of 0. I tried running the code with the url of this page as an example and it returns 0, but there are plenty of divs and spans on this page, so it shouldnt be 0. Its like it tries to bind before the page has loaded

Comment: Try this:  $( "div, span, li, ul, ol, input, button", childwindow.document)